# RadGrid - Batch Editing Multiple Edit-Templates per column

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik

I can create different controls per column depending on data from code behind and it works.

I want to create different controls per each row in code behind.
example:

```
    <EditMode>
          ColumnA             ColumnB
 Row I:   RadComboBox         RadComboBox
 Row II:  RadNumericTextBox   RadNumericTextBox
 Row III: CheckBox            CheckBox
 ...
```

The problem is the Rad-grid Batch mode only have one Control in one Edit-template for each column, that means all the rows have the same Edit-template and control.

this I can Do

```
     ColumnA (RadComboBox)     ColumnB(RadNumericTextBox)
     Row I:   RadComboBox               RadNumericTextBox
     Row II:  RadComboBox               RadNumericTextBox
     Row III: RadComboBox               RadNumericTextBox
```

Is it possible to have Multiple Edit-templates per column or what is my alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add controls to a cell in the grid's ItemDataBound event.  In my example below, I change the cell's contents to the control type you listed instead of just showing its default text ID.  You can do the same based on whatever your condition is.  I populate the example grid with test data in the `rgTest_OnNeedDataSource` method and then apply the changes in the `rgTest_ItemDataBound` method.

aspx:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="rgTest" runat="server" PageSize="10" GridLines="None" AccessKey="0" Skin="Office2007" 
OnNeedDataSource="rgTest_OnNeedDataSource" OnItemDataBound="rgTest_ItemDataBound" AllowFilteringByColumn="true" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ImagesPath="~/Skins/Office2007/Grid/Images">
    <MasterTableView>
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="ID" DataField="ID" SortExpression="ID" HeaderText="ID" HeaderStyle-Width="40px" FilterControlWidth="40px" AllowSorting="true" AllowFiltering="true" AutoPostBackOnFilter="false" ShowFilterIcon="true" />
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Value" DataField="Value" SortExpression="Value" HeaderText="Value" HeaderStyle-Width="80px" FilterControlWidth="40px" AllowSorting="true" AllowFiltering="true" AutoPostBackOnFilter="false" ShowFilterIcon="true" />
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

aspx.cs:

```
protected void rgTest_OnNeedDataSource(object source, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable batchChecks = new DataTable("checksRandomName");
    batchChecks.Columns.Add("ID");
    batchChecks.Columns.Add("Value");
    batchChecks.Rows.Add(new ArrayList() { "1", "ABC" }.ToArray());
    batchChecks.Rows.Add(new ArrayList() { "2", "BCD" }.ToArray());
    batchChecks.Rows.Add(new ArrayList() { "3", "CDE" }.ToArray());
    batchChecks.Rows.Add(new ArrayList() { "4", "DEF" }.ToArray());
    DataSet dsBatch = new DataSet("rcBatch");
    dsBatch.Tables.Add(batchChecks);
    rgTest.VirtualItemCount = dsBatch.Tables.Count;
    rgTest.DataSource = dsBatch;
}

protected void rgTest_ItemDataBound(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
        TableCell cell = item["Id"];
        switch (cell.Text)
        {
            case "1":
                cell.Controls.Add(new RadComboBox());
                break;
            case "2":
                cell.Controls.Add(new RadNumericTextBox());
                break;
            case "3":
                cell.Controls.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox());
                break;
        }
    }
}
```